# How to send stream commit message in gRPC Python Client

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I have a gRPC server on Go Lang and the client is in python. I have one RPC call in which the client initiates a progress stream and after completing the progress it sends a completion message to the server that the stream is finished.

The problem is the client is initiating the stream and committing to every call. I want to send a completion message when the progress reaches 100%.

Here is my RPC call:

```
service DownloadClient{

    rpc Progress (stream ProgressMessage) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}

message ProgressMessage{
    double progress = 1;
}
```

The client code:

```
def sendProgress():
    p = 0
    while p <= 100:
        sleep(1)
        client.Progress(progressMessage(p).send(None))
        p=p+1


def progressMessage(value=0):
        prog = mypb.Progress(progress=value)

        yield prog

sendProgress()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong in your code. focusing on this line

```
client.Progress(progressMessage(p).send(None))
```

what is it trying to achieve? AFAIU this should look more like

```
client.Progress(progressMessage(p))
# where client is a class that has a stub that calls the rpc
# i.e.
# class SomeClient:
#   def Progress(self, the_stream):
#       self.stub.Progress(the_stream)
#
```

see also https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/#calling-service-methods